# Silverlight bind collection to Combobox in DataForm using MVVM

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, mvvm, combobox, dataform

I have this problem, I've got Silverlight app written using MVVM. I need to create DataForm which is binded to property on ViewModel and I want to add ComboBox and fill it with values from other collection in the same ViewModel.

Code:

```
<dataFormToolkit:DataForm CurrentItem="{Binding NewUser, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateFields="False" Height="298">
            <dataFormToolkit:DataForm.EditTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>

                        <dataFormToolkit:DataField Label="Email">
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Email, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        </dataFormToolkit:DataField>

                        <dataFormToolkit:DataField Label="Język">
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Languages, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        </dataFormToolkit:DataField>

                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </dataFormToolkit:DataForm.EditTemplate>
        </dataFormToolkit:DataForm>
```

All this is handled by NewAccountVM which has these properties:

```
private User newUser;
    public User NewUser { 
        get 
        { 
            return newUser; 
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != newUser)
            {
                newUser = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("NewUser");
            }
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Language> languages;

    public ObservableCollection<Language> Languages
    {
        get { return languages; }
        set 
        {
            if (languages != value)
            {
                languages = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Languages");
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, all this works besides adding ItemsSource to ComboBox. I've found many examples showing how fill CB in CodeBehind, but like I said I want to do this in MVVM-Style :)
I understand that, ComboBox inherited DataContext from DataForm, and this ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Languages, Mode=TwoWay}" will not work, but I have no idea how to achieve my goal.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Declare the viewmodel to the view in the resources section.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:MyViewModel x:Key="myViewModel" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

2) Bind the ComboBox to the collection property on the viewmodel.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Languages, 
                                Source={StaticResource myViewModel}, 
                                Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is it :) I've figured it out eriler, but I had problem with my ViewModel because it had 2 constructors, I had to reorganize creation of my ViewModels to this one with static resources.
Thanks again.

Comment: In this example, where do you set the ViewModel as the DataContext for the UserControl? I am assuming you do so in the Constructor of the UserControl, but I would like know for sure.

Comment: @michajas Be careful about setting the VM's inside of the Resources, if your VM ctor throws an exception, it will be swallowed by a XAML parsing error. I would highly suggest looking at setting the VM in the Loaded event and use an IoC container, for greater flexability.

Comment: Combining these two worked for me  http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/08/20/creating-a-silverlight-datacontext-proxy-to-simplify-data-binding-in-nested-controls.aspx     AND    http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2009/11/25/silverlight-and-ria-adding-a-combobox-to-a-dataform.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can set the Data Context in XAML to your static resource like so:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <Binding Source="{StaticResource myViewModel}" />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Scenario A:**
1. Assume you wish to populate a combo with all the membership Roles, and allow the client to select the role and assign to the User :
i.e. ObjectA : Aspnet_Role
i.e. ObjectB : User

1. Let us say **User.MembershipRoleId** is to be bound to **Aspnet_Role.RoleId**
2. Dataform is bound to ObjectB
3. Combobox in dataform is populated with List
4. In XAML write the following:

   `<Combobox DisplayMemberPath="RoleName"
   SelectedValue="{Binding MembershipRoleId,Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedValuePath="RoleId" />`

here the mapping is, ObjectB.MembershipRoleId=ObjectA.RoleId

**Scenario B:**
1. If you do not want to explicitly define by the way in ScenarioA, then in that case, define a ForeignKey-PrimaryKey relationship between the tables in the database like
ForeignKey -> User.MembershipId
PrimaryKey -> Aspnet_Roles.RoleId
2. From the ADO.NET (.edmx) file, update the model from the database, you will observe that in the **User** entity there is an association made upon entity **Aspnet_Roles**
3. In XAML write the code as below to bind the combobox, to the desired field of the Dataform

```
<Combobox DisplayMemberPath="RoleName" SelectedItem="{Binding MembershipRoleId,Mode=TwoWay}" .... />
```